# How to enforce encoding for sqlcipher/sqlite export?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, encoding, sqlcipher

I'm trying to work with the JSON output taken from an sqlcipher output (taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505008/signal-desktop-how-to-export-messages))

```
sqlcipher/sqlcipher -json -noheader "db.sqlite" "PRAGMA key = \"x'"MY-ENCRYPTION-KEY"'\";PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-8\";select * from messages_fts_data;" > messages_fts_data.json
```

but when I try to load the content with a Python3 script I'm getting problems with the encoding:

```
>>> json.load(open("messages_fts_data.json"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 32: invalid start byte
```

(I'm cheating a bit here - in my 'real' code I'm stripping of `b'[{"ok":"ok"}]\n'` first but since I'm getting the error when reading the file it's definitely not just an JSON error)

When I try to handle the encoding manually by specifying `encoding="utf-8"` in the `load()` or `open()` commands, I'm getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong? I *thought* I told `sqlcipher` to generate `UTF-8` encoded output but this seems to not work.

Comment: The encoding pragma is a no-op except in the case of a brand new empty database that hasn't had any tables or anything else created yet, BTW.

Comment: The shadow tables for fts virtual tables store a lot of binary blobs. You would need to encode then in hex or base64 or another textual scheme to store them in json data.